# Adding item to TooltipItems[] in ChartJS doesn't update labelColors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display information from all datasets, always, on a single tooltip in ChartJS, always getting the one data point that is closer to the current time index the user is hovering over. For that, I wrote a function in which I append/modify a tooltip item to the tooltipItems array:

```
var bodyCallback = function(labels, chart) {
        console.log(this);
        var drawnDatasets = labels.map(x => x.datasetIndex);
        var masterSet = labels[0].datasetIndex;
        var stringDate = labels[0].xLabel.substring(0,23);
        var masterDate = new Date(stringDate);
        var index = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < chart.datasets.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != masterSet)
            {
                var closest = closestDateValue(masterDate, chart.datasets[i].data.map(x => x.x));
                if(drawnDatasets.includes(i)){
                    labels[index].yLabel = chart.datasets[i].data[closest].y;
                    labels[index].x = labels[0].x;
                    labels[index].y = labels[1].y;
                    index++;
                } else {
                    labels.push({datasetIndex: i,
                     index: closest,
                     label: chart.datasets[i].data[closest].x.toString(),
                     value: chart.datasets[i].data[closest].y.toString(),
                     x: labels[0].x,
                     xLabel: labels[0].xLabel,
                     y: labels[0].y,
                     yLabel: chart.datasets[i].data[closest].y});           
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The function works well and as expected, since with "displayColors" disabled all tooltip items appear perfectly, however, as soon as I enable colors, this callback function fails to perform the intended purpose as labelColors only contains colors relating to previously present elements in the tooltipItems array (before I add any new ones).

The result is an exception: "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "borderColor", labelColors[o] is undefined", where o is the index for the new appended tooltipItem. I have tried to find a way to modify labelColors directly without messing with ChartJS code, but I had no luck, as most relevant methods to labelColors are private.

The structure for the new tooltipItem is OK, works fine without the colors, it only breaks when I enable them.

Utilizing the labelColor callback doesn't work either, it only affects items that existed previous to adding new ones.

Is there a way to modify the labelColors array present in [plugin.tooltip.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/9c27f748018f54bc3148318150face1f3800209b/src/plugins/plugin.tooltip.js%5D) or a better way to customize which tooltip items shall appear in the tooltip?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remediate that by creating a custom tooltip function and keeping the original one so I could access labelColor

```
var customTooltip = function(tooltip) {
                        if(tooltip.dataPoints != undefined){
                        var i;
                        for(i = 1; i < tooltip.dataPoints.length; i++){
                                tooltip.labelColors.push({
                                backgroundColor: tooltip.dataPoints[i].backgroundColor,
                                borderColor: tooltip.dataPoints[i].borderColor
                                });
                        }
                        }
                };
```